# Follow hyperlink in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I am currently using this code in Powerpoint Macro in VBA to shoot up a browser with a URL:

```
ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink Address:="http://www.participoll.com/faq/", 
                                   NewWindow:=True, AddHistory:=True
```

But this works only when there is an active presentation. I want to execute or invoke a browser to open a hyperlink, even though there is no presentation. Is there an alternate code for the above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mehow Will this `Shell` work with non-admin privileges?

Comment: I have no idea what your non-admin privileges allow you to do. Best shot would be to try it yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add a windowless presentation then close it when done:

```
Dim oPres As Presentation

Set oPres = Presentations.Add(msoFalse)

oPres.FollowHyperlink Address:="http://www.participoll.com/faq/", NewWindow:=True, AddHistory:=True

oPres.Saved = msoTrue
oPres.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using a external dll library

```
Shell "cmd /C ""start http://www.participoll.com/faq/"""
```

should also do the trick.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: For me, it will. Have you tried it an had any problems? If so, then tell me the problems please.